# Suspicious requests to nginx web server

Tags: https, web-development, http, nginx

Periodically, the nginx web server receives a lot of requests from the same IP address:

```
$ cat /var/www/site.com/logs/access.log | grep '213.80.239.170'

213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:11:05:03 +0600] "GET /testlist?s=98 HTTP/2.0" 200 55855 "https://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=testlist?s=98=ru&cts=1678770301390%40%40events%3D%5B%7B%22event%22%3A%22click%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221_irh5w02-01%22%2C%22cts%22%3A1678770301390%2C%22fast%22%3A%7B%22organic%22%3A1%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%22web%22%2C%22event-id%22%3A%22lf7shqryxv%22%7D%5D&mc=2.521640636343318&hdtime=2634.6" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:22 +0600] "GET /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/from?get&nocache=19821 HTTP/2.0" 301 0 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:22 +0600] "GET /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/from HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:23 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:23 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:23 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:23 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:23 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:24 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:24 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:24 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:24 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:15:04:25 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
.... ( > 40000 rows ) ....
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:22:20:21 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:22:20:22 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:22:20:22 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
213.80.239.170 - - [14/Mar/2023:22:20:22 +0600] "POST /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.779 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"


$ cat '/var/www/site.com/logs/access.log' | grep -E '^213.80.239.170' | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr 2>/dev/null | head -10
  48099 /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except
      1 /service.php
      1 /testlist?s=98
      1 /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/from?get&nocache=19821
      1 /558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/from
```

"/558FC106-5249-8240-8812-A133472F1CEC/A7312F5C-A764-2E4D-A7F3-3B35699BC16E/except" what is it?

Comment: Is it the Yandex search bot

Comment: "213.80.239.170" IP does not belong to the Yandex subnet

Comment: Have the same problem with the same UA, different UUIDs. Did you manage to get information about it?